# What is wrong with this JSON

Tags: ios, json, post

I have to send this JSON format to api as post request. But when checked on line on JSONLint it says it is wrong, error. Please guide to create correct. Below is the JSON format:

```
{
"departure_time" = "2017-07-28T17:39:43.611Z";
steps = ({
    "encoded_polyline" = "ytfzDqzksM_AgB";
    "road_name" = "ytfzDqzksM_AgB";
}, {
    "encoded_polyline" = "yvfzDy}ksMPMf@a@";
    "road_name" = "yvfzDy}ksMPMf@a@";
}, {
    "encoded_polyline" = "_ufzDi_lsM}@mB";
    "road_name" = "_ufzDi_lsM}@mB";
}, {
    "encoded_polyline" = "}vfzDwblsMb@a@f@a@";
    "road_name" = "}vfzDwblsMb@a@f@a@";
}, {
    "encoded_polyline" = "qtfzD{dlsMoA}B";
    "road_name" = "qtfzD{dlsMoA}B";
});
vehicle = {
    axles = 2;
};
}
```

Please guide what is wrong in it and how to correct it.

Comment: The `;` should be `,`, the `(` and `)` have to be `[` and `]`.

Comment: but in system this can not be generated i guess

Comment: Neither `=` nor `;` belong in JSON. JSON objects are of form `{ "key": value, "key": value }`, not `{ "key" = value; key = value }`. Arrays are `[val1, val2]`, not `(val1; val2;)`.

Comment: but how can i generate this i created dictionary and set objects in them

Comment: How are you generating this ... thingy that is not json but is supposed to?

Comment: Please check this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000079/how-to-hit-post-request-with-nsdictionary-as-parameter/52000640?noredirect=1#comment90951169_52000640"

Comment: well you may want to use code that has actually anything to do with json, google for it, tons of resources out there.

Comment: You are just saying "printing @_attributes", not how you're doing it. If you're not using `NSJSONSerialization`, you're likely doing it wrong.

Comment: You need NSString declared with data and encoding .utf8

Comment: I'd use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Comment: @Amadan NSJSONSerialization used for parsing not for what i required(send dictionary in json format)

Comment: You are wrong. It is used for both. See [Generate JSON string from NSDictionary in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary-in-ios) for example of JSON generation.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, semicolons must be replaced by comas to separate lines, EXCEPT the last line that doesn't need anything:

```
"encoded_polyline" = "qtfzD{dlsMoA}B",
"road_name" = "qtfzD{dlsMoA}B"
```

To declare an array, use brackets, not parentheses:

```
"steps" = [{
    "encoded_polyline" = "ytfzDqzksM_AgB";
    "road_name" = "ytfzDqzksM_AgB";
}, {
    "encoded_polyline" = "yvfzDy}ksMPMf@a@";
    "road_name = "yvfzDy}ksMPMf@a@";
}]
```

And finally, equals symbols aren't used in JSON. Instead, use colons:

```
"departure_time" : "2017-07-28T17:39:43.611Z"
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't need quotes to define a key. JSON does.

Comment: thanks but i know that, i want to know how to create this format with above data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52000079/how-to-hit-post-request-with-nsdictionary-as-parameter/52000640?noredirect=1#comment90951169_52000640

Comment: I actually told you what was wrong with your format, as you asked for it.

Answer (score -1):

Validated JSON

```
{
    "departure_time": "2017-07-28T17:39:43.611Z",
    "steps": [{
        "encoded_polyline": "ytfzDqzksM_AgB",
        "road_name": "ytfzDqzksM_AgB"
    }, {
        "encoded_polyline": "yvfzDy}ksMPMf@a@",
        "road_name": "yvfzDy}ksMPMf@a@"
    }, {
        "encoded_polyline": "_ufzDi_lsM}@mB",
        "road_name": "_ufzDi_lsM}@mB"
    }, {
        "encoded_polyline": "}vfzDwblsMb@a@f@a@",
        "road_name": "}vfzDwblsMb@a@f@a@"
    }, {
        "encoded_polyline": "qtfzD{dlsMoA}B",
        "road_name": "qtfzD{dlsMoA}B"
    }],
    "vehicle": {
        "axles": 2
    }
}
```

Verified on - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: If it works accept this answer, it will help others as well. @iPhone7